# Logging framework incompatibility

Tags: java, compatibility, apache-commons, slf4j, logback

I'm building a small Java app and hoping to use logback for logging.

My app has a dependency on an older project that does its logging via

```
org.apache.commons | com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging | 1.1.1
```

...so my plan was to use

```
org.slf4j | jcl-over-slf4j | 1.5.6
```

...to redirect the JCL logging to

```
org.slf4j | slf4j-api | 1.6.0
```

...and ultimately to

```
ch.qos.logback | logback-classic | 0.9.22
ch.qos.logback | logback-core | 0.9.22
```

so my app can log through logback via its slf4j API while the old library code can log into the same location via the redirection.

Alas, this results in

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:141)
```

I've tried higher and lower verision numbers on some of these jars and also digging through API documentation and such... but I'm unable to find and solve the problem.

Help, please?

Although logback is considered the "strategic" logging framework, I have some leeway in which logging mechanism I ultimately use. I'd hope to use either logback or log4j, though, and I definitely want to merge the old project's logging into whatever the "new" logging framework ends up being, via a common configuration.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You are mixing the 1.5.6 version of the jcl bridge with the 1.6.0 version of the slf4j-api; this won't work because of a few changes in 1.6.0. Use the same versions for both, i.e. 1.6.1 (the latest). I use the jcl-over-slf4j bridge all the time and it works fine.

Comment: That worked right away, of course; thank you very much! I hadn't used 1.6.1 of those jars because they didn't appear to be available. I'm highly annoyed at m2eclipse, which purports to show me all available versions yet mysteriously drops a significant number of them.

Comment: Just for interest of anyone else following: I ended up with a red arrow in the dependency graph because even the latest logback-core insists on slf4j-1.6.0. It took some more diddling around with versions until all the red arrows disappeared, but now it's both working and all blue arrows.

Comment: How exactly do I do that.

Answer (score 41):

SLF4J 1.5.11 and 1.6.0 versions are not compatible (see [compatibility report](http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/compat_report/slf4j/1.5.11/1.6.0/c87de/bin_compat_report.html)) because the argument list of `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log` method has been changed (added Object[] p5):

SLF4J 1.5.11:

```
LocationAwareLogger.log ( org.slf4j.Marker p1, String p2, int p3,
                          String p4, Throwable p5 )
```

SLF4J 1.6.0:

```
LocationAwareLogger.log ( org.slf4j.Marker p1, String p2, int p3,
                          String p4, Object[] p5, Throwable p6 )
```

See compatibility reports for other SLF4J versions [on this page](http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/slf4j/).

You can generate such reports by the [japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker) tool.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

Just to help those in a similar situation to myself...

This can be caused when a dependent library has accidentally bundled an old version of slf4j.  In my case, it was tika-0.8.   See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-556

The workaround is exclude the component and then manually depends on the correct, or patched version.

EG.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <!-- NOTE: Version 4.2 has bundled slf4j -->
            <groupId>edu.ucar</groupId>
            <artifactId>netcdf</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- Patched version 4.2-min does not bundle slf4j -->
    <groupId>edu.ucar</groupId>
    <artifactId>netcdf</artifactId>
    <version>4.2-min</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got hit by this when trying to use Jackrabbit 2.2.5 with SLF4J 1.6.1 and Logback 0.9.28 !

Comment: Thanks. I linked to your answer here: http://spring-java-ee.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-jackrabbit-jcr-225-with-slf4j-161.html