# Spring Boot SLF4J Error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, slf4j

I have been trying for several days to get the spring boot 15 minute hello world working. I keep encountering the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.warn(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:179)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.callFinishedListener(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:91)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.finished(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:810)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
at com.symphony.Application.main(Application.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I know this question appears elsewhere on the site, I have tried countless things and nothing works. I am using IntelliJ 2016.1.3, Java version 1.8.0._60.

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried maven clean from IntelliJ and no luck.

EDIT: Screenshot added to show everything being pulled into project. 
[Maven Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNLt4.png)

UPDATE: Completely uninstalled maven 3.3.9 and only have the built in maven from IntelliJ ultimate. Still not working, extremely frustrating. Over a week into this and can't get the 15 minute demo working.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have an [incompatibility with versions of logging frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519978/logging-framework-incompatibility). See if replacing the `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-web` artifacts with `spring-boot-starter-web` helps, as per [the current Getting Started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

**Update**

I was able to configure and build the Spring [Getting Started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) guide down to the **Add Unit Tests** heading without error on Intellij Ultimate 2016.2 using its own embedded Maven 3, and on the command-line using Maven 3.1.1 and Java 8 (1.8.0_31-b13).

I found significant build errors and/or execution errors when I:

1. changed the Maven configuration in Intellij to use Maven 2
2. compiled with the `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-web` artifacts rather than `spring-boot-starter-web`.

I think your problem is a build configuration error. Whenever I get these, I go back to command-line to build and run just to be sure the problem isn't an artifact of some IDE bug.

Comment: Great suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. I was really hoping that would do it

Comment: Are you using that same Getting Started guide?

Comment: Start again from the plain vanilla example, some dependency conflict has snuck into your project.

Comment: This is my third clean project, same thing everytime

Comment: Same starter guide ben

Comment: Hmm, what does `mvn dependency:analyze`, and `mvn dependency:tree` report?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the error is coming from Maven? What version of mvn are you running? `mvn -v`

Comment: IntelliJ comes bundled with 3.0.5. I also have 3.3.9 installed on my computer.

Comment: Uninstalled IntelliJ community, downloaded IntelliJ Ultimate and used Spring Initializer plugin. Significantly reduced the error message, see above update.

Answer (score 2):

I've run in the same problem, but got it solved by excluding `logback-classic`

So my pom now Looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you're in Eclipse (idk, if IntelliJ has this Feature too) and look at the dependency hierarchy tab, you'll see, spring-boot itself implements multiple slf4j-apis.
[Visualization of the dependency hierarchy filtered by "slf4j"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAwDU.png)

I know it may be too late for you, but your post was one of the first result by Google, so maybe it'll help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

your pom lists java 8, but you said you are using java 6 for the project.   make sure your project is pointing to a Java 8 ddk.

Comment: Nice catch. Typo, I am using 1.8._60